# How to cancel / prevent PayPal's checkout modal from popping up before a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-buttons

I'm trying to get PayPal's **Server Side REST** to work.

Here is the form I'm working with:

[image]

What I want to do is to **prevent / cancel** the payment if either `amount` or `email` fields are blank.

According to [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server), `payment()` is called after the button is clicked. The docs cover how to handle the "optimistic" use case, however they fail to mention how to **cancel** the payment process:

```
// payment() is called when the button is clicked
payment: function() {

    // Set up a url on your server to create the payment
    var CREATE_URL = '/demo/checkout/api/paypal/payment/create/';

    // Make a call to your server to set up the payment
    return paypal.request.post(CREATE_URL)
        .then(function(res) {
            return res.paymentID;
        });
},
```

Simply returning `null` does not seem to work either. How can this be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly in the `payment()` function, but you can add a `validate()` function which enables/disables the button based on your form state:

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/validation

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thanks